# Use vba to download tif file from aspx search query

Tags: asp.net, vba, download, tiff

I am trying to write a short macro to automate a process of downloading scanned files from a local database.
currently we have a series of queries (seven digit codes) that have to be entered manually into an aspx search page to retrieve the stored matches in an aspx table.

I can use vba to navigate to the location, search for a file, return the results of the search and extract the names of the files listed in the aspx table. however, The problem comes about in trying to download the files from the table
The table itself is dynamic and uses a "mouse hover" to direct each link to the download file location.....

```
</tr><tr class="DocumentListRowMouseOut" onmouseover="this.className = 
'DocumentListRowMouseOver';return true;" onmouseout="this.className = 
'DocumentListRowMouseOut';return true;">
<td class="cellDocList"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_1Rad8452783" 
type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$radDocumentList" value="1Rad8452783"
```

```html
<td class="cellDocList"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_1Rad8452783" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$radDocumentList" value="1Rad8452783" onclick="RadioButtonClicked(8452783);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$1Rad8452783\',\'\')', 0)"></td><td class="cellDocList" align="center"><input id="ctl00_MainContent_Chk18452783" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Chk18452783" onclick="checkboxClicked(this.id, 8452783);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$Chk18452783\',\'\')', 0)" documentlistcheckbox="true"></td><td class="cellDocList"><a href="ViewFile.aspx?DocID=F22E4BED-E95A-3385-9D35-5194685192FC" target="_blank"><span class="NormansHtmlToolTip">Immu_I_20130218_160200_2.tif<span><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="position: fixed; left: 405px; top: 192px;"><tbody><tr><th class="thHead" align="left" colspan="2">Document Index Summary</th></tr><tr><td class="row1" colspan="1" valign="top" align="left">Barcode1</td><td class="row2" valign="top" class="row1" colspan="1" valign="top" align="left">DateScanned</td><td class="row2" valign="top" align="left">18/02/2013 00:00:00</td></tr><tr><td class="row1" colspan="1" valign="top" align="left">TimeScanned</td><td class="row2" valign="top" align="left">01/01/1900 16:02:00</td></tr><tr><td class="row1" colspan="1" valign="top" align="left">Department</td><td class="row2" valign="top" align="left">baking</td></tr></tbody></table></span></span></a></td><td><table class="hoverbox" border="0">
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

btw

the filename in the table is in this code section
class="NormansHtmlToolTip">Immu_I_20130218_160200_2.tif

whilst the download presumably happens through this code
    "a href="ViewFile.aspx?DocID=F22E4BED-E95A-3385-9D35- 5194685192FC"target="_blank""

Comment: Can you share more HTML? The above I am not sure how useful it is. You can simulate the mouseover action if you can select the element with element.FireEvent "onmouseover"

Comment: Can you put an event listener on to see what is triggered when doing the download manually?